# pyspark : select columns with special characters from map type column

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

in a query to select some columns from dataframe, I have a column type : map, which has multiple attributes.
I'm trying to select only few attributes from this column, but this is returning to me an error since some attributes contains special characters like  '-' , 
other attributes of this column are working fine

example :

```
sqlContext.sql("select colA, colB.attribute1 from schema.table")
```

however if i select an attribute that contains - , it fails

```
sqlContext.sql("select colA, colB.4-TRANSPORT from schema.table")
```

=> fails

```
18/08/29 15:21:34 INFO ParseDriver: Parse Completed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/2.5.3.16-1/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 580, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._ssql_ctx.sql(sqlQuery), self)
  File "/usr/hdp/2.5.3.16-1/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/2.5.3.16-1/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 51, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'TRANSPORT'
```

i tried double quote it etc , no luck so far ...

Comment: Have you tried using backslash? eg `sqlContext.sql("select colA, colB.4\-TRANSPORT from schema.table")`

Answer (score 2):

Backquotes will help.

```
sqlContext.sql("select colA, colB.`4-TRANSPORT` from schema.table")
```

updated based on comment.

Comment: Works great but Backquotes  only the column name  :

sqlContext.sql("select colA, colB.\`4-TRANSPORT\` from schema.table")

Thanks lot